# Dynamic Memory Allocation and Heap Corruption

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

For an assignment for school, I need to create a program that takes one array and splices another into it, assigning the first X values of the first array into a new array, then all of the second, and then the rest of the first. It is also required that this is done by means of dynamically allocated arrays. I don't understand why, but for some reason, the heap is becoming corrupted and I can't figure out why. I am just now learning about pointers, so the solutions I have found don't make much sense to me.

If someone could point out exactly what I'm doing wrong, and explain it to me so that I can learn from my mistakes, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

int* createArray(int);
int* splice(int[], int[], int, int, int);
void arrayPrint(int []);

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int firstLength, secondLength, copyLength;

    cout << "Enter the length of the first array: ";
    cin >> firstLength;
    cout << "Enter the length of the second array: ";
    cin >> secondLength;
    cout << "Enter the length of the first array to be copied: ";
    cin >> copyLength;

    int* firstArray;
    int* secondArray;
    int* thirdArray;

    srand(100);

    firstArray = createArray(firstLength);
    secondArray = createArray(secondLength);

    firstArray = new int[firstLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < firstLength; i++)
        firstArray[i] = rand() % 100;
    secondArray = new int[secondLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < secondLength; i++)
        secondArray[i] = rand() % 100;

    thirdArray = splice(firstArray, secondArray, firstLength, secondLength, copyLength);

    cout << "First Array: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < firstLength; i++)
    {
        cout << firstArray[i] << ", ";
    }
    arrayPrint(firstArray);
    cout << endl << "Second Array: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < secondLength; i++)
    {
        cout << secondArray[i] << ", ";
    }
    arrayPrint(secondArray);
    cout << endl << "Spliced Array: " << endl;
    arrayPrint(thirdArray);

    delete firstArray;
    delete secondArray;
    delete thirdArray;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int* createArray(int arrayLength)
{
    int* createdArray;
    createdArray = new int[arrayLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
        createdArray[i] = rand();
    return createdArray;
}

int* splice(int firstArray[], int secondArray[], int firstLength, int secondLength, int copyLength)
{
    int* splicedArray;
    splicedArray = new int[copyLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < copyLength; i++)
    {
        splicedArray[i] = firstArray[i];
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < secondLength; j++)
    {
        splicedArray[j + copyLength] = secondArray[j];
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < firstLength - copyLength; k++)
    {
        splicedArray[k + copyLength + secondLength] = firstArray[k + copyLength];
    }
    return splicedArray;
}

void arrayPrint(int toPrint[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(toPrint) / sizeof(*toPrint); i++)
    {
        if ((i % 10) == 9)
            cout << toPrint[i] << endl;
        else
            cout << toPrint[i] << ", ";
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all you are allocating firstArray and secondArray twice, the main problem is in your splice function, where you have allocated splicedArray of copyLength, but you are putting more values than its length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining C_Raj's answer, vinodsaluja's and Wander3r's comments:

you are allocating first and second arrays twice, once is enough, actually more is memory leak (vinodsaluja).
Logically, since thirdarray is a combination of first and second arrays, its length should be sum of both array lengths, which is firstlength+secondlength not copylength. This is where heap corruption occurs (vinodsaluja).
Finally ararys should be deallocated with delete[] (Wander3r).

C_Raj's code is what the result should be so I'm not copying it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! This solved it, and you explained it in a simple enough manner that I understand.